# How can FFmpeg record from FIFO without an "invalid data" error?

Tags: pipe, ffmpeg, fifo

I have an internet calling infrastructure that can result in audio being played through speakers in the following way:

```
aplay -r 48000 -c 1 -f S16_LE - < contact/call_out
```

Here, `call_out` is a FIFO file. Instead of playing through speakers, I want to record to sound file. I have attempted to use `FFmpeg` in the following way:

```
ffmpeg -y -i contact/call_out -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le out
```

However, when the sound stream from the FIFO file stops or when `FFmpeg` is stopped using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, I am presented with the following error:

```
contact/call_out: Invalid data found when processing input
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 1 -i contact/call_out out.wav
```